# ¿Cómo puedo enviar un pdf en python usando UDP entre cliente-servidor?

Tags: python

He encontrado como hacerlo usando TCP pero no con UDP, y la verdad que no tengo mucha idea de python. Gracias

Comment: Ten en cuenta que UDP limita el tamaño de cada envío a 64K. Por tanto si tu archivo es mayor necesitarás trocear y enviar cada trozo en un datagrama separado. Además, ya que UDP no garantiza las entregas en orden (ni siquiera las entregas), necesitarás inventar un protocolo que numere los trozos, y para que el servidor pueda reordenarlos antes de guardar el fichero, y pueda detectar si falta alguno. Y debes decidir qué hacer si faltan trozos ¿debe el servidor responder al cliente algún error? ¿Debe reenviarse el trozo que falta? ¿Debe darse por fallida la transmisión completa?

Comment: Por todo lo anterior, UDP no es lo más adecuado, y se usa TCP para este tipo de cosas. ¿por qué quieres hacerlo con UDP?

Comment: Es un ejercicio de la universidad :D, por lo que tan solo un ejemplo simple me ayudaría mucho

Answer (score 1):

Todo depende del nivel de sofisticación y recuperación ante errores que quieras implementar.

El envío y recepción de un datagrama es bastante simple:

```
# Cliente (envía)
import socket

nodo = "ip.del.servidor"
puerto = 8000 # por ejemplo

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
datos = open("fichero.pdf", "rb").read()
s.sendto(datos, (nodo, puerto))
```

```
# Servidor (recibe)
import socket
puerto = 8000  # por ejemplo

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(("", puerto))
datos, origen = s.recvfrom(65507)
print("Recibido datagrama de longitud %d desde %s" % (len(datos), origen))
open("guardado.pdf", "wb").write(datos)
```

El problema es que el tamaño de un datagrama está limitado a 65507 bytes. Por tanto el fichero que transmitas de este modo ha de tener un tamaño menor.

Si es mayor, entonces tendrás que tener un bucle en el cliente que vaya leyendo trozos y enviandolos en datagramas sucesivos por el socket. El servidor tendría otro bucle en que va recibiendo del socket datagramas y los va escribiendo sucesivamente en un fichero. Para que el servidor sepa cuándo acabar, el cliente debería enviar un último datagrama con alguna marca especial (por ejemplo un datagrama vacío).

Aún así puede haber problemas si la red no es muy fiable o cliente y servidor están en diferentes subredes, debido a que UDP no garantiza la entrega en orden, ni detecta errores en caso de que un datagrama se pierda. Eso te obligará a diseñar tú mismo un protocolo en el que cada datagrama tenga un cierto formato fijo (inventado por ti) que comience por ejemplo con 4 bytes que indican el "numero de trozo" y otros 65503 que sean los "contenidos del trozo". De este modo al menos el servidor podría saber en qué orden debe guardarlos y si alguno de los trozos se perdió. De ese modo como mínimo podrías informar al usuario "la transferencia ha ido mal" y no escribir el pdf resultante que de todas formas estaría corrupto.

Un diseño más avanzado podría consistir en que el servidor vaya enviando al cliente un mensaje tipo "ok" por cada datagrama correctamente recibido (irían también numerados para indicar a qué "trozo" se le está dando el "ok"). El cliente podría reenviar los trozos para los que no haya recibido "ok" en un tiempo razonable. El servidor debería descartar trozos que puedan llegarle duplicados. Todo esto naturalmente es complejo y acabarías inventando algo similar a TCP.